# AX 2009 error: The length of the specified literal string exceeds max limit

Tags: sql-server, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

When saving a `SalesLine`, changing only the `Name` field, the `doUpdate` method will occasionally throw an error exception:

> The length of the specified literal string exceeds max limit.

When the string length of Name is 128 the `doUpdate` succeeds.
When the string length of Name is 129 the `doUpdate` fails (but sometimes it succeds if you change the characters).

The `Name` field has a defined length of 1000 character (`nvarchar(1000)` in the database).

It fails in the production system, but not in the test system!

Database logging is not enabled. The Database is SQL 2008 R2. AX kernal version: 5.0.1500.5660

Anyone seen this error?
Any hints to resolve?

Comment: if you input directly into the field via SQL server, do you encounter the same limitation?

Comment: Is this a systematic update and what's the frequency of occurrence?  If you can put a try/catch/breakpoint in production, and dump out the SQL that's being run, then try what AnthonyBlake said and run it manually in SQL to see if the same error happens.  If you can isolate it to just SQL it'd be much easier to diagnose.

Comment: Good idea to get the SQL using the AX SQL trace. Will try that tomorrow.

Comment: Well, AX shows an empty SQL expression in the log. I think the AX blows in the generation the SQL expression (UPDATE statement).

Comment: I have a couple of questions:does it fail if you run update() instead of doUpdate()? You stated that sometimes it succeeds if you change the characters, does any change work or are you replacing specific characters?

Comment: The call is `doUpdate` from the `SalesLineType.update` method. The failure was data depended, in one case I had 999 'l' characters, replacing the last with '!' would succeed, with '.' it would fail. But it did it consistently even after a restart.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use literals in query.
I quess in salesLine datasource init method you use literals.
Like:

SalesLine_ds.query().literals(true);

Answer (score 0):

It is possible quotename is being used in sql server 2008?

There appears to be an issue with the length restriction being 128 characters in this version of SQL server

http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/watchout-when-using-quotename-2/

Comment: I don't think AX uses QUOTENAME, as I have never seen an SQL statment with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this behaviour too.
It must be something in combination with the literals as posted by David. Do you use `literals` or `placeholders` in your query?

I can perfectly reproduce this in kernel 5.0.1600.2967 (on the salestable).

It has to be a bug with the combination of `forceliterals` and `doUpdate()`

Changing the field to data type memo or some other changes like changing the `cachelookup` didn't help either.